# Best method for limiting float precision comparison in Python doctest

Tags: python, floating-point, doctest

I'm working on a Python version of a library that has other versions with well-established results. Because of this, I have lines in my docstrings such as

```
>>> air_f(0,0,0,0.9,300.,1.)
-95019.5943231
```

where the precision is within what all versions should agree on. If I run `doctest` on this code, it expects instead the value `-95019.59432308903` which is consistent, but higher precision. In another case, `8.50371537341e-04` is rejected in favor of `0.0008503715373413415`, which only has 1 more digit of precision but a different format.

I know of a few ways to deal with this. I could go through and change all of the numbers to the full precision, or add in print formatting statements before each of them to only match the accuracy. The problem is that each of the 50+ individual files in the library can contain dozens of these lines, and the particular format string is different for each. I've seen [numtest](https://github.com/boisgera/numtest), but I don't know if it's mature (plus I'm having trouble installing it).

I am hoping there is some way to expand on the construction

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

so that `doctest` uses a weaker test of float equality. Adding that into 50 files is much more manageable than changing 1000+ individual lines. I'm unfamiliar with `doctest` though, so I don't know if that's possible or how to proceed. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I spent the time to look at `doctest` and came up with the following. It seems to work for the all the ways my `float`s are formatted, but I would definitely appreciate suggestions on how to make it more robust, how to pass all the options, etc. (In my case it's especially easy, as *all* of my docstring tests would be floats or lists of floats, so I have not tested other use cases.)

---

```
import doctest

def extractsigfmt(numstr):
    """Find a standard formatter from a string.
    From a string representing a float, find the number of
    significant digits and return a string formatter to standardize
    its representation.
    """
    # Pull out the digits term, removing newline and accounting
    # for either E or e in exponential notation
    digs = numstr.lower().rstrip('\n').split('e')[0]
    # Separate from decimal point, removing sign and leading zeros
    res = digs.split('.')
    if len(res) == 1:
        l, r = res, ''
    else:
        l, r = res
    l = l.lstrip(' -+0')
    nsig = len(l) + len(r)
    # Create a standardized exponential formatter
    fmt = '{:+' + '{0:d}.{1:d}'.format(nsig+6,nsig-1) + 'e}'
    return fmt

# Create new OutputChecker class
class fltOutputChecker(doctest.OutputChecker):
    """OutputChecker customized for floats.
    Overrides check_output to compare standardized floats.
    """
    def check_output(self,want,got,optionflags):
        """Check whether actual output agrees with expected.
        Return True iff the actual output agrees with the expected
        output within the number of significant figures of the
        expected output.
        """
        fmt = extractsigfmt(want)
        want_std = fmt.format(float(want))
        got_std = fmt.format(float(got))
        return (want_std == got_std)

def testfun(n):
    """Function to test new OutputChecker on.
    >>> testfun(0)
    -6.96239965190e+05
    >>> testfun(1)
    8.01977741e-10
    >>> testfun(2)
    -95019.5943231
    >>> testfun(3)
    0.164195952060
    >>> testfun(4)
    -0.687329742959e-3
    >>> testfun(5)
    0.876543210e3
    """
    testlist = [-696239.9651898777,8.01977740740741e-10,
        -95019.59432308903,0.1641959520603997,
        -0.0006873297429586108,876.54320956893102]
    return testlist[n]

# Construct and run doctest on this function
finder = doctest.DocTestFinder()
dtlist = finder.find(testfun)
checker = fltOutputChecker()
runner = doctest.DocTestRunner(checker)
for dt in dtlist:
    runner.run(dt)
results = runner.summarize(verbose=True)
```